# Smarty print json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, smarty

Am new to Smarty, i have a json array, my json array looks like following format

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "venue": "Test Venue1",
        "game_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "venue": "Test Venue 2",
        "game_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }
]
```

Tried

```
{foreach from=$gamearray key=k item=v}
            <li>{$k}: {$v}</li>
        {/foreach}
```

Its display like this way

```
0: [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "venue": "Test Venue1",
        "game_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "venue": "Test Venue 2",
        "game_date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
    }

]
```

I just want to show venue field only.

My php looks like this way

```
  $stmt = $this->core->dbh->query($sql);
            $listgame = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $game_array = json_encode($listgame);
$app->render('base.tpl', array('gamearray'=>$game_array));
```

Please help me to solve this.. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't `{$v.venue}` give you `venues`?

Comment: thanks for quick reply, i have edited my question with more info, i tried $v.venue nothing displayed just '0: [' only

Comment: If you pass this from json_decode() it may be an array of StdObject that Smarty cannot process. I write a small code piece to turn all StdObject to real array (still nested, by recursive function) before passing to Smarty and {$v.venue} should work. See if this helps!

Comment: I just tried 
$game_array = json_encode($listgame);
$game_array = json_decode($game_array);

then $v.venue. Now its display venue only. But i think something is wrong by doing this way.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, in my MVC applications, I use Smarty to output HTML and *completely bypass it to output JSON*.

That is, **I simply print the result of PHP's [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/json_encode) for outputting arrays as JSON**. There's no reason at all to involve Smarty in this.

You'd struggle, anyway, to write a recursive Smarty template; it's not expressive enough for that. This isn't a failing of Smarty *per se*: it's not designed for such uses.

Comment: I have edited my question to include my php code too. Can u check

Comment: @Dibish: That doesn't change my answer. I would write `print json_encode($listgame)` and be done with it. No need for Smarty.